# Why can my import not be found?

Tags: python, importerror

I have a project of this structure:

```
src/
    __init__.py
    folder_A/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
    folder_B/
        __init__.py
        bar.py
```

In my `src/folder_A/__init__.py` I import some instance variables from `foo.py`

```
from .foo import variable_a as A
```

Now I want to use that variable in my `bar.py` file so I do the import:

```
from src.folder_A import A
```

But that doesn't work, though if I do:

```
from src.folder_A.foo import variable_a
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try importing your variables from the `src/__init__.py`.

Comment: How would I do that? I thought by doing `from src.folder_A import A` I'm already doing that?

Comment: I replicated your folder structure, and calling `from folder_A.foo import variable_a` in the source in `src/__init__.py` seems to work. Try that and let's see if that works for you.

Comment: That works, though would it be the correct way to do it? Since now I am just moving all the init stuff outside